# No EGLConfig found error even after enabling Host GPU emulation

Tags: android, andengine, gpu, android-virtual-device

I am trying to get this error off for hours. I am using *AndEngine* for game development. I *do have* enabled Host GPU, restarted eclipse as well as AVD many times, but this exception still pops up. I have tried changing emulator's CPU to both ARM and Intel Atom (x86), but couldn't resolve this issue. My AVD specifications are as follows:

[image]

**Manifest file have:**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
```

**Log-Cat**

[image]

I don't know what else to provide here. If you need any further details, just ask me. Thanks.

Comment: As you mention enable GPU emulation when you create your AVD.

Comment: I have already mentioned in my post that I have enabled it. Please refer attached screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AVD you configured looks perfectly fine.

As iDev suggested, using the latest SDK Tools and targeting an higher API level may help.

Your logcat shows that EGL thinks that the Emulator itself lacks GPU support so I suspect your troubles come either from your graphic card drivers or from too old Android SDK tools.

What's your gpu ? You should try upgrading its driver to their latest version.

Comment: I have tested with API 16,18 but still unable to launch app. I am using Android sdk 22.2.1.

Comment: I have ATI Radeon HD 4550 with approx total mem = 2265 MB.

Comment: Your GPU supports OpenGL 3.2, this definitely seems to be a driver issue.

You can try this one: http://www2.ati.com/drivers/beta/amd_catalyst_13.4_legacy_beta_vista_win7_win8.exe (latest AMD Catalyst legacy beta)

and refer to this topic: http://www.eightforums.com/graphic-cards/34538-ati-radeon-hd4550-opengl-2-win-8-1-a.html to get more information.

Comment: Solved. I upgraded my graphics driver. Thank you so much. I wish I could give u more upvotes ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if these make a difference, but are you using "Android SDK Tools - Rev 19", and SDK platform 15.

And while it's probably not related to your problem, I'd also suggest using the Intel Atom x86 system image - it give great performance increase.

Also try changing your API level in the AVD to 16 or 17 - just to help isolate the issue.

or

this was a problem with my graphics card setup

or

qemu? Sounds like your using Linux, let me guess.. Ummmm, 64bit? You'll need to install both qemu and the 32bit OpenGL drivers (not installed by default).

Comment: I am using Android SDK Tools Rev 22.2.1. and "Android SDK platform-Tools rev 18.0.1. I will let u know soon after testing for higher level API's. I need to install them.

Comment: And I am not using linux. I am developing on windows.

Comment: Sorry for late update.. I am still getting same error on API level 16,18 emulator. May be I should give it a try on device after buying. May be my graphic card issue.. Any other guess?

Comment: @anum90 what is your graphic card memory size

Comment: I have ATI Radeon HD 4550 with approx total mem = 2265 MB.

Answer (score 1):

After getting so much trouble with simple AndEngine application, I tried simple project with **Libgdx**. I got an exception saying:

> OpenGL is not supported by the video driver.

So finally and actually that means my video graphic card *does not* support OpenGL!

If you want to know OpenGL support by your Graphics Card, do either of the following:

1. Follow [this](http://www.ononesoftware.com/support/607/) link or
2. Run **dxdiag** from windows start menu, go to display tab, see your graphic card name and google its specifications. Search for *openGL* word there in webpage. You will most probably find supported OpenGL version by you Graphic Card.

Hope it will help others. Thanks to @iDev and @ph0b for helping me.